# Flutter: responsive Positioned in Stack

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, flutter-layout, flutter-positioned

I want to place icon out of parent bounds and make it responsive (relative to parent's height).

[image]

There is no problem to place an icon outside from parent bounds with `Stack` and `Positioned` widgets.

But there is a problem to make it responsive.

So, if container height decreases, then the icon size should also decrease.

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: Color(0xff2577ff),
      width: 5.0,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(15.0),
    ),
  ),
  width: 200.0,
  height: 80.0,
  child: Stack(
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
    children: [
      Center(
        child: Text('Text'),
      ),
      Positioned( // <-- doesn't work
        top: -20.0, // <-- how to make it also relative to parent's height parameter?
        right: -20.0, // <-- how to make it also relative to parent's height parameter?
        child: FractionallySizedBox( // <-- doesn't work
          heightFactor: 0.5,
          child: Image.network('https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOkkG.png'),
        )
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

I've tried to make some sample but with no success. I really don't know how to implement such logic with Flutter and I can't find any reliable example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html). You can get the parent's constraints using that. So, for example:

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Color(0xff2577ff),
            width: 5.0,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(15.0),
          ),
        ),
        width: 200.0,
        height: 160.0,
        child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
          return Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                // <-- doesn't work
                top: -(constraint.maxHeight /
                    4), // relative to parent's height
                right: -(constraint.maxHeight /
                    4), // relative to parent's height
                child: Container(
                    height: constraint.maxHeight / 2, // relative to parent's height
                    width: constraint.maxHeight / 2, // relative to parent's height
                    child:
                        Image.network('https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOkkG.png')),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Text'),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        }));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solves this problem. But would be nice if Flutter add something like `FractionallyPositioned` widget to the core.